# getting incomplete result executing mssql stored procedure in codeigniter

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures

this gives accurate result in mssql server

```
execute proc_Attn_Mon_General 801, '2018-04-14', '2018-05-14', 0
```

but this gives incomplete result

```
$query = $this->db->query("execute proc_Attn_Mon_General @emp_id='$emp_id', @date_from='$start_date', @date_to='$end_date', @Aflag=0");
return $query->result_array();
```

or this

```
$query = $this->db->query("execute proc_Attn_Mon_General ".$emp_id.",'".$start_date."','".$end_date."', ".$Aflag." ");
return $query->result_array();
```

am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What does incomplete result means? Are there any error messages? What is the driver for SQL Server (sqlsrv, mssql)? Thanks.

Comment: there are no errors. some dates are missing

Answer (score 1):

```
the query works fine but this could be issue of your slow network connection
```